# localhost is not working on browser but i can ping it

Tags: apache, debian, localhost, tor

am using debian , and am working on a php laravel project
so first thing to do is

```
sudo service apache2 start
sudo service mysql start
```

every thing working fine , the project is working great my sql is working ,
the problem is in the browser i when i go to localhost or 127.0.0.1 or localhost/phpmyadmin
it gives me Unable to connect

How ever i can ping localhost it give me this result

> 64 bytes from localhost (::1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms

and ping 127.0.0.1 result :

> 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms

so i assumed that the problem in hosts file that the domains is not resolving for a reason ,
am not sure what happend , last thing i was doing i was trying to install tor service and browser
please help me , all my work is on hold , and i tried many things . 
i also thinking that it might be a DNS problem.

Comment: Make sure the webserver is actually running, maybe there is a configuration error. If you are using Debian Jessie (8) or higher, use `systemctl status apache2`. You may also check `netstat -tlpn` to see if port 80 is bound.

Answer (score 1):

This means that your application is running under a different port. When not specifying a port, your browser will assume 80 for http and 443 for https traffic.
Try other commonly used ports like 8080 or 8000:

http://localhost:PORT

ping has nothing to do with your web server, by using it you can check if a host is reachable.

Comment: this solved my problem. i'm using nginx. i changed the port in my config file from 443 to 80.